# remove object from image

Tags: image, image-processing

I have few thousands of images from our vendors. They are models wearing fashion clothing. I need to take only the clothes part of the images and discard the rest and make them transparent background. All the images has one color background but they are in different colors. Currently we perform the following steps manually and I need suggestion and help if there is a way to do this automatically or is there a way to do the manual process faster. We used Gimps and script-fu for automating some part of this process (see below steps), but still the remaining manual part is very time consuming. Is there any tool or any programming language or script that can make this process faster?

This is the way we are doing now:

1. We use Gimps script-fu run in batch to make all images background transparent.
2. Load one by one each image into Gimps manually
3. Via Free select took, we mark around the clothes
4. Remove everything outside the marked clothes area
5. Export and save image into png format.
6. Run script-fu in batch to auto crop all the image

I haven't figure out a way (code or script) to do the step 3 automatically. Does anyone know if that even possible? If it is not, is there any tool that could combine step 4-6 into one control key so reduce the key strokes and any faster way to finish these images?

---

Thank you for your suggestions. This is what I am thinking to do for making my step 3 and 4 automated. Do you think if this approach would work. Is there better way to handle it?

All the images will have transparent background via our batch job. So the idea is to remove the body part now.

1. Auto crop all the images, so the head and feet to be the topmost and bottommost of the image.
2. Code a PHP program to detect the skin colors from list of database colors for skin.
3. Then go to each pixel of image and detect where the skin color starts.
4. Start from topmost of image, the first pixel has skin color must be the head or neck part. I remove everything above the starting first pixel, so I will be able to get rid of hairs if the image has model with full head. Anything below could be the face and neck, I will just replace the color with transparent background. I still don't know how to get rid of hair in right and left side of the face.
5. Searching from bottom of image pixels by pixel until match to skin color. I remove everything from that pixel to bottom of the page. This way I can get rid of shoes parts as well. 
   6.Replace remaining skin part with transparent background.

The problem is the hand sometimes cover the clothes and I am not sure how to handle that. Perhaps if the adjacent pixel is not transparent background then leave that part alone.

I also don't know how to handle the the clothes(dress or blouse) that may have the same color as skin?

Comment: Well, u could chroma key backgrounds, but depends on several factors the final quality of the border. Can one see one of this pictures?

Comment: put a newline after your "this is the way we are doing now", go get your list to look like an actual list. Couldn't edit your post because it's only one 'character' edit, although I did retag your post because "processing" is a programming language, you wanted image-processing

Comment: Thank you for your response regarding using Chroma key background? The Script-Fu that we run in batch, it gets rid of all solid background color. The manual part is to get rid of the head, hands and feet and keep only the clothes part of the image. Can I use the Chroma key for that purpose (step 3 in my list)? Below is sample of image. Some of the images have full head and face. Original Image
http://www.virtualoutfits.com/vo/prodimgs/originalimage/34919.jpg Result image:
http://www.virtualoutfits.com/vo/closetimage/34919.png Thank you in advance for your help *emphasized text*

Comment: not sure if I got this right, but there's 2 things to remove: the background (a flat colour) and the person wearing it. haven't used gimp/script-fu but I'm hoping there's a way to do a colorspace conversion to YCrCb so you can isolate the skin and remove it - this might still cause holes in the outfits. it does sound like a tricky problem

Comment: Yes tha tis correct. I am looking for a way to remove the person wearing the clothes and keep just the clothes. Isolate the skin and remove it would be good idea. What do you think of my approach I just posted?

Answer (score 0):

Step 3 can be semi-automated.  That is, done in such a way that it requires far less human interaction than you are currently using.  I get the impression from your question, that you are not a programmer.  So, I'll point you to a specific off the shelf tool called [Power Stroke](http://www.digitalfilmtools.com/powerstroke/).  It plugs into non-free tools.  There may be a GIMP equivalent.  I don't know.